# How to compare table data structure

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How to compare table data structure. 
    1. Any table added or deleted.
    2. Any column in the tables added or deleted.

So my job is to verify if any table or columns are added/deleted on 1st of every month.

My plan is to run a sql query and take a copy of entire list of tables and it's data type only (NO DATA) and save it in txt file or something and use it as base line, and next month run the same sql query and get the results and compare the file. is it possible? please help with the sql query which can do this job.

Comment: you are approaching this the wrong way. _Any_ change to the schema definition should be done through a SQL script, that script needs to be put under version control and the changes have to be deployed through those scripts. If you do that, you don't need to "compare" structures. Tools like Liquibase or Flyway will help you with that.

Comment: Okay A HORSE, i'm not a DBA guy, i know these guys do it their way and i don't need SQL scripts as of now. I have access to SQL Developer and i don't exactly know the query on how to fetch list of tables along with its data structure for a user "ABCD" that's all. I don't need any tool either.

Comment: Look at dbms_metadata.get_ddl

Comment: Similar question on DBA Stack Exchange: http://serverfault.com/questions/26360/how-can-i-diff-two-oracle-10g-schemas

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you a list of all tables and their columns for a given user (just replace ABCD in this query for the user you have to audit and providing you have access to all that users tables this will work).

```
SELECT  table_name,
    column_name
FROM    all_tab_columns
WHERE   owner = 'ABCD'
ORDER
BY  table_name,
    column_id;
```

This answers your question but I have to agree with a_horse_with_no_name that is not a good way implement change control, most notably because the changes have already happened.

This query is very basic and doesn't give you all the information you'd need to see if a column has changed (or any information about other objects types etc), but then you only asked about additions and deletions of tables and columns and you can compare the output of this script to previous outputs to find the answer to your allotted task.